# Find the ratio of the area of two triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles

$P$ and $Q$ are the midpoints of $AB$ and $BC$ respectively. $S$ and $T$ and the midpoints of $PR$ and $QR$. Find the ratio of area of $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle PQR$
[image: Refer to this figure]

Don't forget to include your approach towards solving the question. Things to look out for.

My work. I can figure out ratio of area of $\triangle RST / \triangle RPQ = 1/4$. 
Same for the ratios of the area of $\triangle BQP/\triangle BCA =1/4$. Can't figure out what to do next.

Comment: Are you assigning us homework? We don't like that....

Comment: @Ajax Please show what you have done and where you are stuck on. It's great you have done this in your other posts, but please do the same on this one.

Comment: @TobyMak I have updated whatever I could think.

Comment: @GerryMyerson No! It is a question from practice set for my MBA entrance exam. Spent an hour and still couldn't figure out.

Comment: @RobertZ It is not given.

Comment: "Don't forget to include your approach towards solving the question!!!" Things to look out for. Don't forget!!!

Comment: @Raffaele What went inside your mind when you saw the question. What things you looked for? It would be great if you could share. I could replicate those things next time when faced with similar questions.

Comment: @TobyMak Can you think of something?

Comment: Bunch of mid-point theorem and similarity.

Comment: hint: your next step could be to assert that PQ is parallel to AC, hence ST= ..

Comment: My point, Ajax, was that your question was phrased the way a teacher would phrase homework for her students. That will get you some negative reactions, as indicated by the three close votes.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $|ST|=\frac{1}{2}|PQ|=\frac{1}{4}|AC|$ (see  G Cab's comment), and 
$$\frac{|\triangle ASP|}{|AS|}=\frac{|\triangle STR|}{|ST|}=\frac{|\triangle TCQ|}{|TC|}$$
(try to figure out why these equalities hold).
Therefore, since $|\triangle STR|=\frac{1}{4}|\triangle PQR|$, it follows
\begin{align}
|\triangle ASP|+|\triangle TCQ|
&=\frac{|AS|+|TC|}{|ST|}\cdot |\triangle STR|\\
&=\frac{|AC|-|ST|}{|ST|}\cdot |\triangle STR|\\
&=3|\triangle STR|=\frac{3}{4}|\triangle PQR|.
\end{align}
Finally $|\square PQCA|=\frac{3}{4}|\triangle ABC|$
and $|\square PQTS|=\frac{3}{4}|\triangle PQR|$, yield
$$\frac{3}{4}|\triangle ABC|=|\square PQCA|=(|\triangle ASP|+|\triangle TCQ|)
+|\square PQTS|=\frac{3}{2}|\triangle PQR|$$
that is the ratio $|\triangle ABC|/|\triangle PQR|$ is equal to $2$.

Answer (score 1):

By the Midsegment Theorem, we know that $\overline{PQ}\parallel\overline{AC}$. Let's draw a couple more parallels, through $B$ and $R$.

[image]

Recall that *families of parallel lines cut transversals in equal ratios*. Since $\overleftrightarrow{PQ}$, $\overleftrightarrow{AC}$, $\overleftrightarrow{A^\prime C^\prime}$ cut $\overline{PR}$ (and $\overline{QR}$) equally, they cut $\overline{PA}$ and $\overline{QC}$ equally. We conclude that all four lines are equally-spaced, creating a trisected perpendicular $\overline{A^\prime B^\prime}$.

Thus, $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle PQR$ have equal heights relative to bases $\overline{AC}$ and $\overline{PQ}$. Since, again by the Midsegment Theorem, $|\overline{AC}| = 2|\overline{PQ}|$, necessarily

> $$|\triangle ABC| = 2|\triangle PQR|$$